# No setter/field found on class but variable names are correct

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, getter-setter, rating-system

I am trying to implement a star rating system using Firebase realtime database and I get the following error:

```
No setter/field for rating found on class com.andrea.uncut.ui.Model.Post
```

I know this can happen when variables are not named the same as in the database but in this case they are:

```
public class Post {
    private String  postID;
    private String  postImage;
    private float  rating;
    private String  title;
    private String  description;
    private String  publisher;

    public Post(String postID, String postImage, float rating, String title, String description, String publisher) {
        this.postID = postID;
        this.postImage = postImage;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public Post() {
    }

    public String getPostid() {
        return postID;
    }

    public void setPostid(String postID) {
        this.postID = postID;
    }

    public String getPostImage() {
        return postImage;
    }

    public void setPostImage(String postImage) {
        this.postImage = postImage;
    }

    public float getRatingScore() { return rating; }

    public void setRatingScore(float rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }
}
```

[image: Database screenshot]

All the other variables work fine so could it be anything related to the type being float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getRatingScore` and `setRatingScore` would be used for a property called `ratingScore`.

Your property is called `rating`, so it would need to be `getRating` and `setRating`.

The private internal properties have nothing to do with how Firebase sees them when setting data on the model class.

Plus, `postID` should be `getPostID` and `setPostID` for consistency.

Comment: Thanks a lot that solved it, I did not know also getters and setters needed a precise name. Thanks again!